# Numeric keypad in Windows Phone 7.5 browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, internet-explorer-9, mobile-browser

How to bring the numeric keypad in webpage which is opened in Windows Phone 7.5 browser and i am able to do it in android webkit browser and iphone safari using the code like,

```
<input type=”number”/> or <input type="text" pattern="\d*"/>
```

But unable to do it in windows phone 7.5 browser?.Always alpha Query keypad is shown instead of numeric keypad in windows phone 7.5 browser.

Is anyway to do this in Windows Phone Browser.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unfortunately unsupported on Windows Phone 7.5 and Internet Explorer 9.
Windows Phone 8 brings the [support of HTML5 input elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673544%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with Internet Explorer 10.

Comment: Thanks for ur help.got struck in this since morning.